# Form Textarea Data Not Being Replaced on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textarea

I'm trying to replace new lines with line breaks when submitting a form with textarea data.

The following works:

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
    $(".description").html($(".description").val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />"));
});
```

Only when I don't change the value of the textarea.

To clarify, this stops working the moment I edit the text in the textarea. Only way to make it work with the newly entered text is to submit the form, click on edit again, and resubmit the form without doing any alterations to the text in the textarea. Can someone explain why this behavior is occurring please?

HTML:

```
<textarea class="form__item__input description" name="description"></textarea>
```

Comment: add your html as well

Comment: Its not fully clear what you want to do. replace only when submitting or replace every time text is being changed ?

Comment: @Alon_A On submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    
  $(".description").val($(".description").val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <textarea class="description" rows="10">
    Hi
    Click
    me 
    please
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't add the line breaks if I edit the text in the textarea.

Comment: so it means when you enter line break during edit it should add <br/> ?

Comment: Yes, but only when I submit.

Comment: @Frisbetarian try updated answer. I hope this helps. You can also edit your existing input.

Comment: That did the trick. Kind of odd how html() is behaving. Could you perhaps explain why it wasn't updating please?

Comment: This works because you are preventing the form from being submitted, so you get to see the actual change in the text (page is not refreshing to the `action` of the form). If you do want to submit the data, add `e.submit();` after the replacement.

Comment: @Frisbetarian html() does not give you 'latest' dirty value but values of initial DOM element state. val() overcomes on that.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: @Alon_A Tried that but got a "too much recursion" error due to infinite callbacks.